# XProc p:store href variable when using xsl:result-document

Tags: xslt, xpath-2.0, xproc

I'm using XProc to run an XSLT that spits out numerous result-documents (using the xsl:result-document). I'm unsure how to go about adding a variable for the @href in the  step. I've got the below XProc:

```
<p:declare-step xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc"
xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step" version="1.0">
<p:input port="source">
    <p:empty/>
</p:input>

<p:xslt name="pagelist">
    <p:input port="stylesheet">
        <p:document href="file:/C:/page-list.xsl"/>
    </p:input>
    <p:input port="source">
        <p:document href="file:/C:/toc.xml"/>
    </p:input>
    <p:input port="parameters">
        <p:empty/>
    </p:input>
</p:xslt>
<p:store name="pagelist" indent="true">
    <p:with-option name="method" select="'xml'" />
    <p:with-option name="href" select="" />
</p:store>
```

How do I add a variable in the XProc that will match the output filename from the xsl:result-document?

XSLT snippet, if needed:

```
<xsl:result-document href="{xhtml:a[@class='ref-uri']/@id}_pagelist.xml" method="xml" include-content-type="no" indent="no">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Calabash 1.1.30 from the command line I was able to get the following to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:declare-step xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc" xpath-version="2.0"
    xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step" version="1.0">
    <p:input port="source">
        <p:empty/>
    </p:input>

    <p:output port="result" primary="true" sequence="true">
        <p:pipe port="result" step="secondary-storage"/>
    </p:output>

    <p:xslt name="xslt-pagelist" version="2.0">
        <p:input port="stylesheet">
            <p:document href="page-list.xsl"/>
        </p:input>
        <p:input port="source">
            <p:document href="toc.xml"/>
        </p:input>
        <p:input port="parameters">
            <p:empty/>
        </p:input>
    </p:xslt>

    <p:store href="toc-list.html"/>

    <p:for-each name="secondary-storage">
        <p:iteration-source select=".">
            <p:pipe port="secondary" step="xslt-pagelist"/>
        </p:iteration-source>
        <p:output port="result">
            <p:pipe port="result" step="store"/>
        </p:output>
        <p:store name="store">
            <p:with-option name="href" select="document-uri(.)"/>
        </p:store>
    </p:for-each>

</p:declare-step>
```

So basically a `p:for-each` over a `p:iteration-source` that uses the `secondary` result output port from the `p:xslt` step and then inside simply uses `document-uri(.)` to have the result URI. All this requires `xpath-version="2.0"`.

Somehow oXygen 22 doesn't run the code but gives me an access denied error, it seems to be set up to write secondary documents to the oXygen installation directory which with normal Windows security settings is not allowed and is not a place where you want result files anyhow; to fix that problem I have adjusted the XProc to have the XML input as a input source to the whole XProc script, then in the `p:xslt` step I can use the function `p:base-uri` to set the `output-base-uri` for XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:declare-step xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc" xpath-version="2.0"
    xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step" version="1.0">
    <p:input port="source">
        <p:document href="toc.xml"/>
    </p:input>

    <p:output port="result" primary="true" sequence="true">
        <p:pipe port="result" step="secondary-storage"/>
    </p:output>

    <p:xslt name="xslt-pagelist" version="2.0">
        <p:with-option name="output-base-uri" select="p:base-uri()"/>
        <p:input port="stylesheet">
            <p:document href="page-list.xsl"/>
        </p:input>
        <p:input port="parameters">
            <p:empty/>
        </p:input>
    </p:xslt>

    <p:store href="toc-list.html"/>

    <p:for-each name="secondary-storage">
        <p:iteration-source select=".">
            <p:pipe port="secondary" step="xslt-pagelist"/>
        </p:iteration-source>
        <p:output port="result">
            <p:pipe port="result" step="store"/>
        </p:output>
        <p:store name="store">
            <p:with-option name="href" select="document-uri(.)"/>
        </p:store>
    </p:for-each>

</p:declare-step>
```

That way Calabash from the command line and within oXygen behave the same, writing the results to the same directory as the input source comes from.

Comment: I can run in oXygen 22 but I get a page-list.xsl is not a stylesheet. It essentially gets overridden from the document-uri(.), I think, instead of saving each individual file with a new name.

Comment: @user2093335, I tried to identify in the oXygen forum whether the problem is with the way oXygen embeds Calabash or with the used XProc code, they say it is a problem with the way I have set up the XProc code, the secondary result documents end up in the oXygen installation directory or are not written at all if access is denied. I am currently unsure whether it is really necessary to change the XProc code as it runs fine outside of oXygen, when I call Calabash from the command line. Anyway, consider adding the tag for XProc to your question, hopefully then someone more knowledgeable helps.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for looking into it. I thought I had the XProc tag but I see it is XPath. Seems like maybe a oXygen implementation problem.

Comment: @user2093335, I have added a slightly improved XProc example that set `output-base-uri` on the `p:xslt` step with the use of the `p:base-uri` function to give more control on where the result files are stored to.

Comment: Works beautifully now! Thanks for digging into this, Martin, I really appreciate it.